# Changing code to make it parallel

Tags: c, operating-system

```
   #include <conf.h>
   #include <kernel.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #define MAX_ITEMS 50
   typedef long double LD;
   int run_solve_equ();
   void xmain(){
       int pid;
       pid = create(run_solve_equ, 20*INITSTK, INITPRIO, "B", 0);
       resume(pid);
   }
   int solve_equ(LD b, int n, LD a[], int choosen[] ){
       if ( n == 1 )
           if (a[0] == b) {
               choosen[0] = 1;
               return 1;
           } /* if */
           else if (b == 0) {
               choosen[0] = 0;
               return 1;
           } /* else if*/
           else {
               choosen[0] = 0;
               return 0;
           }
       else /* n > 1 */
           if (solve_equ(b, n-1, a, choosen)) {
               choosen[n-1] = 0;
               return 1;
           } /* if */
       else if (solve_equ(b - a[n-1],n-1, a, choosen)) {
           choosen[n-1] = 1;
           return 1;
       } /* else if */
       else{
           choosen[n-1] = 0;
           return 0;
       }
   } /* solve_equ */
   LD a[MAX_ITEMS];
   int choosen[MAX_ITEMS];
   char pstr[200];
   extern long int tod;
   int run_solve_equ() {
       int n, i, result;
       LD b, sum;
       printf("How many numbers? No more than %d:", MAX_ITEMS );
       scanf("%d",&n);
       puts("Enter b:");
       scanf("%Lf",&b);
       a[0] = 1;
       for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
           a[i] = a[i-1]*2;
       result = 0;
       sprintf(pstr, "time = %ld\n", tod);
       printf(pstr);
       result = solve_equ(b,n, a, choosen);
       sprintf(pstr, "time = %ld\n", tod);
       printf(pstr);
       sprintf(pstr, "Solution for b = %Lf, n = %d, value = %d :\n", b,
           n,result);
       printf(pstr);
       printf("\ni:\n");
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           sprintf(pstr, "%-16d",i);
           printf(pstr);
       } // for
       printf("\na[i]:\n");
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           sprintf(pstr, "%-16.1Lf", a[i]);
           printf(pstr);
       } // for
       printf("\nchoosen[i]:\n");
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           sprintf(pstr, "%-16d", choosen[i]);
           printf(pstr);
       } // for
       printf("\n");
       sum = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
           if (choosen[i]) {
               sum += a[i];
               sprintf(pstr, " + %-16.1Lf", a[i]);
               printf(pstr);
           } /* if */
       sprintf(pstr, " = %-16.1Lf\n", sum);
       printf(pstr);
       return 0;
   }
```

I need to change this program so the search will be "parallel" by two processes:
Each will search a n-1, the first user on a [n-1] and the other not.
the problem is to find a number in the array that all the number togother are equal to another number b !

Comment: How much do you pay ?

Comment: As other has said, give it a shot. Try to pass in an argument of the range each thread should process....one way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but I do have some constructive comments for you.

Reading the above code hurts.  It hurts my eyes and it hurts my brain.  Why?

1. Variable Names are non-descriptive an often one letter (outside of I).  `b`, `n`, `a` - I don't know what these are at a glance and I don't want to find out by understanding what you wrote.  I bet you won't understand what you wrote next week either.  Do everyone a favor and make the names better.
2. Please, please use a bit of white space between your "code thoughts".  Your code looks like one long run-on sentence that also hides what it does.
3. Don't mix braced and non-braced code - especially when your indentation is not consistent.  It is very, very difficult to follow your if logic as-is right now.  Go ahead and waste a few bytes of hard disk space and perhaps .25 seconds adding braces or at least fixing your indents.
4. Write useful comments. `/* if */` is a terrible comment and you do similar stuff everywhere.  I know what an if is, but perhaps a quick not of what you are checking?
5. Don't mix globals and extern defines in the middle of your code.  Keep them together and it makes it easier to remember what is global and what is not.  This is the most minor offense though and others may disagree.

Anyways, a bit off topic for your question, which will more than likely close as you've put little effort into solving it yourself, but my comments may help you with future coding projects and will at least make it easier for others to help you going forward.